# Joint PDF for a uniformly distributed random point

Tags: probability

Let (X,Y) be a uniformly distributed random point in the bounded region between the curves y = x^2−1 and y = 1−x^2. Write down the joint pdf for (X,Y).

I understand that the region between the two points (-1,0) and (1,0) is 8/3, but was wondering how to use this to find the joint PDF and its bounds.

Answer (score 0):

A uniformly continuous distributed random vector has a constant probability density for every point in the support, and the constant is *inversely proportionate* to the Lebesgue measure of the support (in this case, that is the area).

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac 1{\lambda(S)}~\mathbf 1_{(x,y)\in S}$$

Now, you know that the support is: $~S=\{(x,y): -1\leqslant x\leqslant 1~,~ x^2-1\leqslant y\leqslant 1-x^2\}$ and the area of this is indeed $\lambda(S)=8/3$.

So you are basically done.

> $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac38~\mathbf 1_{-1\leqslant x\leqslant 1~,~ x^2-1\leqslant y\leqslant 1-x^2}$$